# Spring Boot ReactiveCircuitBreaker configuration not working

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I'm using a circuit breaker implementation in my reactive web service built on Spring Boot Webflux. I'm using below dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</parent>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And then I created the beans related to Circuit Breaker:

```
@Configuration
public class NetworkProfileCircuitBreakerConfig {
...
    @Bean("networkProfileCircuitBreakerFactory")
    public ReactiveCircuitBreakerFactory networkProfileCircuitBreakerFactory() {
        return new ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory();
    }
    
    @Bean 
    public ReactiveCircuitBreaker networkProfileCircuitBreaker(@Qualifier("networkProfileCircuitBreakerFactory") ReactiveCircuitBreakerFactory factory) {
        return factory.create("networkProfileCircuitBreaker");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> circuitBreakerCustomizer() {
        return factory -> {
            factory.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                    .circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
                            .failureRateThreshold(failureRate)
                            .minimumNumberOfCalls(minimumNumberOfCalls)
                            .slidingWindowSize(slidingWindowSize)
                            .enableAutomaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpen()
                            .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofMillis(waitDurationInOpenState))
                            .ignoreExceptions(BadRequestException.class)
                            .build())
                    .timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom()
                            .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofMillis(timeLimiter))
                            .build())
                    .build());
            factory.addCircuitBreakerCustomizer(circuitBreaker -> circuitBreaker.getEventPublisher()
                    .onStateTransition(e -> {
                        switch(e.getStateTransition().getToState()) {
                            case CLOSED:
                                log.info("Circuit Breaker is now CLOSED.");
                                break;
                            case HALF_OPEN:
                                log.info("Circuit Breaker is now HALF_OPEN.");
                                break;
                            case OPEN:
                                log.info("Circuit Breaker is now OPEN!");
                                break;
                            case METRICS_ONLY:
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }), "circuitBreakerStateTransitionEvents");
        };
    }

}
```

Then I autowired the `ReactiveCircuitBreaker` bean to my service in order to use it in my reactive call:

```
...
@Service
public class NetworkProfileService {
...
    @Autowired
    private ReactiveCircuitBreaker networkProfileCircuitBreaker;

...
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<NetworkProfileResponse>> getNetworkProfile(NetworkProfileRequest request) {
        return networkProfileCircuitBreaker.run(adapter.getData(request)
                , throwable -> {
                        //Fallback method
        });
    }
}
```

However, it seems like my `ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory` is not working properly; the circuit breaker seems to be using default settings instead of my customized settings.
I have tried may things including moving the Factory to my `Service` class constructor; to no avail.

Is there anything that I might have missed?

Comment: I'm facing the same, did you find the solution?

Comment: @Federico unfortunately not yet, even after I opened an issue at their github

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my workaround was to do it manually (in *buildConfiguration* method you can add the config):

```
  @Bean
  public ReactiveCircuitBreaker reactiveCircuitBreaker(ReactiveCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory){
    return reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory.create("id");
  }

  @Bean
  public ReactiveCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory() {
    ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory = new ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory();
    reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory.configureDefault(buildConfiguration());
    return reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory;
  }

  private Function<String, Resilience4JCircuitBreakerConfiguration> buildConfiguration() {
    Resilience4JCircuitBreakerConfiguration resilience4JCircuitBreakerConfiguration = new Resilience4JCircuitBreakerConfiguration();
    CircuitBreakerConfig breakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig
        .from(CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults())
        .build();
    resilience4JCircuitBreakerConfiguration.setCircuitBreakerConfig(breakerConfig);
    resilience4JCircuitBreakerConfiguration.setTimeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom()
        .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofMillis(TIMEOUT)).build());
    return (id -> resilience4JCircuitBreakerConfiguration);
  }
```